# Facebook Graph API feed not working

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm completely new to Facebook Graph API.

I'm trying to use the Graph API Explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

I got the token, I'm using GET method and version 2.5 of FQL, and following is the query itself:

> me?fields=id,name,picture,feed

The result from that query unfortunately only includes the id, name and picture but does not include the posts. I also tried to write "posts" instead of "feed", but the result was the same.

This is what I get:

```
{
   "id": "123456789",
    "name": "John Smith",
    "picture": {
            "data": {
              "is_silhouette": false,
              "url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/very-long-url"
            }  
      } 
}
```

As you can see, nothing about the posts.

I also tried to open a new Chrome tab and go directly to this URL:

> https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=very-long-token

And this is what I get for that:

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Any help will be profoundly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try with user_posts permission?
Maybe you forgot this...

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/user/feed

> Your app needs user_posts permission from the person who created the
>   post or the person tagged in the post. Then your app can read:
>   Timeline posts from the person who gave you the permission. The posts
>   that other people made on that person Timeline. The posts that other
>   people have tagged that person in.

Cheers